# Can't figure out how to get space around an image?

Tags: images

If you go to [this page](http://12e.bc0.myftpupload.com/about/) you will see the text is butted up against the right side of the headshot picture. I've tried plugins and codes, etc., but nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how I can get some padding around the picture so the text won't be right up against it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for just this image, you can edit that post and in text editing mode you could add something like this around the link to the image:

```
<span style="float:left;padding:10px;"> ...<img>image link here... </span>
```

If you are looking to fix this for any image that is added to posts, you'd need to add a rule similar to this to your .css for the theme you are using.  Some themes allow custom css to be added, check the settings/options for your theme.

```
img[class*="wp-image-"] {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: PERFECT! I was able to use the second suggestion and add it to the custom CSS just for that page and it worked perfect. THANK YOU!